# undefined method `url' for #<ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy []>

Tags: ruby-on-rails, carrierwave

This is my `Post` controller create action:

```
def create
  @user = current_user
  @post = @user.posts.create(post_params)

  respond_to do |format|
    if @post.save
      format.html { redirect_to @post, notice: 'Post was successfully created.' }
      format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @post }
    else
      format.html { render :new }
      format.json { render json: @post.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end
```

private:

def post_params

params.require(:post).permit(
        :title, :description, :size, images_attributes [:id,:image,:imageable_id,:imageable_type])

end

end

This is `show.html.erb`:

```
(<%= image_tag @post.images.url %>)
```

This is the `Post` model:

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :images, as: :imageable
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :images
end
```

This is the `Image` model:

```
class Image < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :imageable, polymorphic: true
  mount_uploader :image, ImageUploader
end
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're using Carrierwave and have mounted it on the `image` attribute of the Image model. Therefore something like this will likely work:

```
<% @post.images.each do |image| %>
  <%= image_tag image.image_url(:original) %>
<% end %>
```

You can replace `:original` with whatever versions your carrierwave uploader file creates

Comment: how to check which version carrierwave file creates?

Comment: By default Carrierwave will create a version called :original so the code above should work as is, and you can find out which other versions Carrierwave creates by looking inside `app/uploaders/image_uploader.rb`

Comment: in my image_uploader the version is thumb.i replace it with :original but image is not displayed     '<%= image_tag image.image_url(:thumb) %>'

Comment: Have you uploaded an image? Also I can see a typo in your post_params method, it should have a colon after the images_attributes key like so: `images_attributes: [:id,:image,:imageable_id,:imageable_type]`

Comment: You'll likely need to upload your image again

Answer (score 0):

`<%= image_tag @post.images %>` gives a `collections of images` belongs to the `@post`

**To render the images of post do this:**

```
<% @post.images.each do |img| %>
  <%= image_tag img.url %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: image is not displayed.